# Print results for a specific date mysql+php

Tags: php, mysql, date

Hi everybody) I have table and few rows. How I can print all results for a specific date? Specific date like this - 30.01.2013 . Date previously saved in $date (in variable).

Google helped me), but it for last month..:

```
select id from tab where date_format(real_time, '%Y%m') = date_format(date_add(now(), interval -1 month), '%Y%m');
```

The date save in row TIMESTAMP.

Answer (score 0):

```
select ...
from ...
where real_time = '2013-01-30'
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I have date in this type: 2013-01-30 18:26:30

Comment: when `where date(real_time) = '2013-01-30'`. You should go read the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html). mysql's very flexible for date/time operations, but it's not psychic.

Comment: I should to select my date from all rows, change it in 30.01.2013 format then, if refresh_date = 30.01.2013 echo "Hello world"? yeah?)